# Meteor MongoDB find last element

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to perform a query in my MongoDB using JS in Meteor.
How do I find the last element that's available for subscribed user, in other words, I have my collection with following elements.

- Year:

  Month:

  Day:

  createdAt:

  userId:

  Car:

Car value is often different, how do I get last Car from most recent createdAt? Just that Car value element, not everything.

Answer (score 1):

Did it. This is the query

```
var lastCar = Trips.findOne({}, {fields: {car:1}, sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 1}).car;
```